# Packing a compiled Android kernel for Odin

Tags: android, kernel, android-source

I have compiled my kernel, now what are the right steps to have it ready to be flashed?

Comment: Not familiar with "Odin" but I've flashed many kernels and ROMS. you probably need to provide more details: specifically phone model, how you compiled it, is phone rooted/unlocked, what have you tried, etc. Generally, flashing just a kernel involves using a script called "split_bootimg" to get the initrd out of an existing kernel build, and then running a script called "mkbootimg" to "glue" the initrd back together with the compiled zImage to create a new boot.img, which can then be flashed using clockworkmod or fastboot (or another recovery).

Comment: @transistor1 it's Samsung S5660 EUR, i will take a look for scripts.